.htaccess redirecting to blank page instead of index.php
as in title I have a problem i have a problem with redirecting all nonexistent url's to index.php file.
When I try to access a url that does't exist I get a blank page.
I tried setting up a .htaccess file:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php

Here's my file structure:
file structure
index.php is available at localhost, when trying anything else (eg. localhost/abc) redirection doesn't work.
I also changed AllowOverride to all in httpd.conf.

I am using RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA] instead of RewriteRule . /index.php to do the same. Perhaps it will work for you too? So a real regular expression to match any file name and not starting at the root of the file system. You can find what the QSA means here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html

Also, consider trying the more modern one line FallbackResource directive

So what does your http server's error log file reveal what the issue is?
